# Populate details activity with Firebase Real Time Database after click on RecyclerView

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i want to click in my recyclerview and open a new activity to show the datails. Ultil now i
have accomplished to open the activity and show the values "interno" and "siniiga" with the next intent. how can i get "madre and padre" values from firebase? applying the method to add father and mother, then I will use it for the rest of the values ​​that the xml shows.  excuse my horrible code. if someone know a different method, let me know

attached code and images.

**Main Activity**

```
    RecyclerView rv;
    List<cow> vacas;
    adapter adapter;
    ImageButton mbuttoninf;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewGirdView);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        vacas = new ArrayList<>();


        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        adapter = new adapter(vacas);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);


        database.getReference("Vacas").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                vacas.removeAll(vacas);
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 :
                        snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    cow vaca = snapshot1.getValue(cow.class);
                    vacas.add(vaca);
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

    }
```

**cow**

```
    String interno;
    String siniiga;
    String ulr;
    String madre;
    String padre;


    public cow() {
    }

    public cow(String interno, String siniiga, String ulr, String madre, String padre) {
        this.interno = interno;
        this.siniiga = siniiga;
        this.ulr = ulr;
        this.madre = madre;
        this.padre = padre;
    }


    public String getInterno() {
        return interno;
    }

    public void setInterno(String interno) {
        this.interno = interno;
    }

    public String getSiniiga() {
        return siniiga;
    }

    public void setSiniiga(String siniiga) {
        this.siniiga = siniiga;
    }

    public String getUlr() {
        return ulr;
    }

    public void setUlr(String ulr) {
        this.ulr = ulr;
    }

    public String getMadre() {
        return madre;
    }

    public void setMadre(String madre) {
        this.madre = madre;
    }

    public String getPadre() {
        return padre;
    }

    public void setPadre(String padre) {
        this.padre = padre;
    }
}
```

**Adapter**

```
    List<cow> vacas;
    Context context;


    public adapter(List<cow> vacas) {
        this.vacas = vacas;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public cowviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_vaca,parent,false);
        cowviewHolder holder = new cowviewHolder(v);
        return holder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final cowviewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final cow vacaslist = vacas.get(position);
        holder.textViewinterno.setText(String.valueOf(vacaslist.interno));
        holder.textViewsiniiga.setText(String.valueOf(vacaslist.siniiga));
        Glide.with(holder.imageviewrec.getContext()).load(vacaslist.getUlr()).into(holder.imageviewrec);
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),detailactivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("keyint", vacaslist.getInterno());
                intent.putExtra("keysin", vacaslist.getSiniiga());
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return vacas.size();
    }

    public static class cowviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textViewinterno, textViewsiniiga, tvmadre, tvpadre;
        ImageView imageviewrec;


        public cowviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewinterno = itemView.findViewById(R.id.interno);
            textViewsiniiga = itemView.findViewById(R.id.siniiga);
            imageviewrec = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgrec);
            tvmadre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvmadre);
            tvpadre = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvpadre);

        }


    }
```

**detailsactivity**

```
   TextView textView;
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.informationfire);

       TextView tvinterno = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvinterno);
       TextView tvsiniiga = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsiniiga);


       String vinterno = "";
       String vsiniiga = "";



       Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
       if (extras !=null);
       vinterno = extras.getString("keyint");
       vsiniiga = extras.getString("keysin");
       
       tvinterno.setText(vinterno);
       tvsiniiga.setText(vsiniiga);
       
   }
   
}
```

**firebase**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6Yri.png)

and the xml for details

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t8L0.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you are getting data from firebase you saving that data in a Object and then add that object to list, so your list contains objects , so you can pass through the intents same way as you are doing others.

```
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent=new Intent(v.getContext(),detailactivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("keyint", vacaslist.getInterno());
                    intent.putExtra("keysin", vacaslist.getSiniiga());
                    intent.putExtra("madre", vacaslist.getMadre());
                    intent.putExtra("padre", vacaslist.getPadre());
                    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```